# Does putting vehicle in neutral at slope cause clutch plate spoilage?

Tags: motorcycle, clutch, gears, hero-honda

I am having a **Hero Honda Passion** 2002 model motorcycle. I have a doubt regarding **clutch and Neutral functionality**.

I have observed that most of the time in our city the roads have ups and down so there is no point of engaging the vehicle into gear during slopes because it maintains good speed when I put my bike into Neutral.

Today when I went to a mechanic he told me that my clutch plates are worn out. That creates a question in my mind, *can using too much Neutral cause worn out clutch plates in the above scenario*?

Comment: People wear out clutches by not using them properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having your bike in neutral will cause no additional wear on the clutch. When you have your bike in neutral and you have re-engaged the clutch (released the handle), the clutch is fully engaged without any torque being applied to it like it would normally see when in gear.

The only way a clutch sees wear is when it is slipping. This is when you pull the handle to disengage the clutch and releasing the handle to re-engage it (while in gear). If you are *slipping* the clutch (keeping the handle in partially with the clutch partially engaged) a lot of the time, this is where you will see the most wear occur in your clutch.